# How to map a deeply nested array of items from external data

Tags: multidimensional-array, rxjs

I've done a mapping before, but not this deeply nested.  I am trying to re-populate data from a corrupt db.  I have manually reconstructed an orders array.  I'm trying to look up data for each player, and then update the fields (which start out null) for each player:

Example:  I start with data like this:

```
const orders = [
{
"paymentID": "ch_456", 
"paymentStatus": "PAID", 
"user": "kingkong@gmail.com", 
"cart": {
  "username": "kingkong@gmail.com", 
  "totalQty": 1, 
  "totalPrice": 80, 
  "items": [{
    "event": "Men's BB", 
    "division": "Men's", 
    "level": "BB", 
    "group": "nonpro", 
    "field": "PAL", 
    "day": "Saturday", 
    "numplayers": 2, 
    "price": 80, 
    "players": [{
      "avp_id": 1042641, 
      "first": "King", 
      "last": "Kong", 
      "waivers": [], 
      "completed": true, 
      "country": "USA", 
      "signed": false}, 
      {
      "avp_id": 1086117, 
      "first": "Jacob", 
      "last": "Ladder", 
      "waivers": [], 
      "completed": true, 
      "country": "USA", 
      "signed": false, 
      "shirt_size": "N/A"}], 
    "net": null, 
    "team": null, 
    "notes": null, 
    "paymentNote": null, 
    "waiversSent": false, 
    "active": true, 
    "paymentID": "ch_456", 
    "users": ["kingkong@gmail.com"], 
    "paymentStatus": "PAID", "__v": 4}]},
"__v": 0
},{
"paymentID": "ch_123",
"paymentStatus": "PAID",
"user": "marymac@aol.com",
"cart": {
  "username": "marymac@aol.com", 
  "totalQty": 1,
  "totalPrice": 50,
  "items": [{
    "event": "Junior Boys 16s",
    "division": "Junior Boys",
    "level": "16s",
    "group": "nonpro",
    "field": "Main",
    "day": "Friday",
    "numplayers": 2,
    "price": 80,
    "players": [{
      "avp_id": 1022228,
      "first": "Some",
      "last": "Kid",
      "waivers": [],
      "completed": true,
      "country": "USA",
      "signed": false
      }, {
      "avp_id": 1020142,
      "first": "Justin",
      "last": "Kid",
      "waivers": [],
      "completed": true,
      "country": "USA",
      "signed": false,
      "shirt_size": "N/A"
      }
    ], 
    "net": null, 
    "team": null, 
    "notes": null, 
    "paymentNote": null, 
    "waiversSent": false, 
    "active": true, 
    "paymentID": "ch_123", 
    "users": ["marymac@aol.com"], 
    "paymentStatus": "PAID", "__v": 4
    }
  ]
},
"__v": 0
}];
```

Here is my code, which I'd like to get the data from an API, and update player info to pass into a function further down:

```
async getLostData() {
    // get the lost orders
    console.log('start lost data import');
    // this.adminService.GetLostOrders().subscribe(orders => {
    //   console.log('load each order into system', orders);
orders.forEach(order => {
    order.cart.items.map(item => {
      const players = item.players.map(async player => {
         player = await 
           this.adminService.adminAVPReg(player.last, player.avp_id)
           .toPromise(); 
          console.log("updated player outside subscribe", player);
      });
      item.players = players;
      console.log("item", item);
    });
    // load order with updated info, create registration, and skip pmt
    // this.adminService.LoadLostOrders(order).subscribe(data => {
    //   console.log(data);
    //   console.log('finished');
    // });
  });
  console.log("orderlist", orders);
// });}
```

The data I'm getting logged is interesting.  What comes back first from the logger is each item, followed by orderlist, and then the updated player info.  Each item shows the players array listed as ZoneAwarePromise.  I have no idea how to replace that with the actual data, but I can see it's not being logged in the order I expected.

How can I get the item to return with the updated data?

[image: item logged, showing ZoneAwarePromise for player data]
[image: updated info logged]

Comment: What is the use of this.adminService.LoadLostOrders(order)? And is it order or orders?

Comment: That will take the completed order and save it to the database.  Then it will transform the order data into respective registrations.  Usually these things are done when a user checks out, and the data is added as each player is added.  Now I need to get the player data from an API since the data was lost and I'm trying to recover it.

Comment: Did you try to implement the solutin I gave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood you are trying to do, I came up with this,

```
this.adminService.GetLostOrders().pipe(
  mergeMap((orders: any[]) => from(orders).pipe(
    mergeMap((order) => from(order.cart.items)),
    mergeMap((item) => of(item).pipe(
      mergeMap(_ => from(item.players)),
      mergeMap(player => this.adminService.adminAVPReg(player.last, player.avp_id).pipe(
        map(newPlayer => { player = newPlayer; return player; }))
      ),
      toArray(),
      tap(newPlayerArray => item.players = newPlayerArray)
    )),
    toArray(),
    mergeMap(_ => this.adminService.LoadLostOrders(orders))
  ))
).subscribe();
```

OP's Edit
I implemented what you shared above, and turned it into this:

```
getLostData() {
    // get the lost orders
    console.log('start lost data import');
    // get manually created orders from lostdata collection
    this.adminService.GetLostOrders()
    .pipe(
      mergeMap((orders: any) => from(orders).pipe(
        mergeMap((order: any) => from(order.cart.items)),
        mergeMap((item: any) => of(item).pipe(
          mergeMap(_ => from(item.players)),
          mergeMap((player: any) => this.adminService.adminAVPReg(player.last, player.avp_id).pipe(
            map((newPlayer: any) => { 
              player.avp_id = player.avp_id;
              player.signed = player.signed;
              player.waivers = player.waivers;
              player.country = player.country;
              player.completed = true;
              player.sandbagger = false;
              player.first = newPlayer.first;
              player.last = newPlayer.last;
              player.email = newPlayer.email;
              player.address = newPlayer.address;
              player.city = newPlayer.city;
              player.state = newPlayer.state;
              player.zip = newPlayer.zip;
              player.shirt_size = newPlayer.shirt_size;
              player.ranking = newPlayer.ranking;
              player.overallRanking = newPlayer.overallRanking;
              player.notes = player.notes;
              player.phone = newPlayer.phone;
              player.adult = newPlayer.adult;
              return player; }))
          ),
          toArray(),
          tap(newPlayerArray => item.players = newPlayerArray)
        )),
        toArray(),
        tap(_ => { this.loadlostOrders(orders);
        })
      ))
    )
    .subscribe();
  }

  loadlostOrders(orders) {
    orders.forEach(order => {
      this.adminService.LoadLostOrders(order).subscribe((data) => {
            console.log("success", JSON.stringify(data));
          }, (error) => {
            console.log("error", JSON.stringify(error));
          });
    });
  }
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer and am trying to incorporate it.  I'll have to do a little researching on mergeMap, as I've not heard of that one before.  Thank you!

Comment: I tried this but got an error that pipe is not a function at MergeMapSubscriber.project at this line " mergeMap(player => this.adminService.adminAVPReg(player.last, player.avp_id).pipe"

Comment: Can you share your code somewhere on stackblitz, with dummy API Response?

Comment: I got it to work!  In my admin service, I had LoadLostOrders converted to a promise.  When i removed that it worked.  I still get an error, but I think it's because I only wanted to pass one order at a time to the backend, so I changed the last line to call a function passing orders into it.  That function sends each order into the LoadLostOrders() function.

Comment: I haven't had much luck with stackblitz, but I posted what is working other than a type error above, as an edit to what you shared.  I had to modify it a bit to get the desired data so it works until I try to run ionic build --prod.  Then I get a type error but don't know how to fix it.

Comment: You were getting that error because mergeMap expects an Observable but you were passing a function with void type i.e. loadlostOrders(). I have fixed it by changing the last mergeMap with tap. Now It shouldn't give you the error.
Also I was not sure whether you wanted to pass orders array or a single order in the loadlostOrders(), as it can be seen you are passing single order. I will simplify the answer a bit later, so that you won't have to do subscription twice. RIght now you can change the last mergeMap with tap. It should work without error.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!  Now you've got me wanting to try it the other way with the observable, and see which way is better.  If I may ask, is there a video course you know of that explains some of this better, so I can learn more?

Comment: There is no single source for learning. You will find lot of articles on medium about rxjs. For starters,  https://blog.angularindepth.com/learn-to-combine-rxjs-sequences-with-super-intuitive-interactive-diagrams-20fce8e6511 . Just Practice!!!